# Whats the most efficient way to remove the first element from a large vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Say I have a vector with 100000 elements, and I wish to iterate through the vector, one by one, whilst copying the element into a map of some sort, but during each iteration, deleting the element from the vector - what is the most efficient way to do this?

Whilst iterating through the vector, I had done something like "it = vec.erase(it)" but it takes absolutely ages to complete. Is there not a quicker way? And as a side note, ordering is very important...

Comment: Are you going to erase every element in the vector? Can you not just call `clear()` at the end?

Comment: Do not use vector. Use different container.

Comment: How is ordering important when putting the elements in a container that does its own ordering anyways?

Comment: Uhhm, vector prevents the order you put the elements in if you use push_back @BaummitAugen, but this definitely sounds like a job for queue or linked list..

Comment: @Anedar But a map usually does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't one.  You are using the vector as a queue.  This goes against its design.

You have a few choices.  The following come immediately to mind:

- Don't erase one item at a time.  Do them in batches.
- Use the vector as a ring buffer and just advance an index, but never remove elements.
- Use a more appropriate container such as `std::deque`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the order of the elements in the vector can not be important - you are putting them in the map anyways - the easy solution is to swap the first element with the last, and than remove the last element. That is going to be much faster.

Comment: If you were going to do it that way, you might as well avoid the swap and just process the vector in reverse, popping each time.

Answer (score -3):

If you need to use a `vector`, then given your requirements, you should use a `vector` of pointers to dynamically-allocated instances of the objects instead of a `vector` of objects themselves.

Comment: Nah, no confusion. My idea was based on their possible desire to stick with a `vector`. In that case, `vector<SomeMaybeBigElement>` would perform a lot worse than 'vector<SomeMaybeBigElement *>` when it comes to removing elements. Without more details on what they are really trying to do, I was only focusing on `vector` use.